# Multiply columns in a DT by DT[i,j]

Tags: r, data.table

Question 1: line 1 throws an error. Why and how to multiply all columns by DT[i,j]?
Question 2: line 2 works but are there better ways to multiply all other columns by one column?

```
df=data.table(matrix(1:15,3,5))
df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) {x*df$V5), .SDcols = c("V1","V2","V3","V4")] #line 1
df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) {x*df[1,"V5"})}, .SDcols = c("V1","V2","V3","V4")] #line 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we are multiplying one column with the rest, either do the multiplication of the Subset of Data.table directly

```
df[, .SD * V5, .SDcols = V1:V4]
```

---

Or with `lapply`

```
df[,  lapply(.SD, `*`, V5), .SDcols = V1:V4]
```

Note that in both cases, we are not updating the original dataset columns.  For that we need `:=`

```
df[, paste0("V", 1:4) := .SD * V5, .SDcols = V1:V4]
```

---

In the OP's code, there is a closing `}` missing in the `line 1`

```
df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) {x*df$V5), .SDcols = c("V1","V2","V3","V4")] 
                                      ^^
```

It would be

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) { x* V5 }), .SDcols = V1:V4]
```

Here, we don't really need those curlies as well as within the data.table, column names can be referenced as unquoted instead of `df$` along with the shortened version of `.SDcols` where column names are represented as a range (`:`)

Comment: Thanks!  Line 2 doesn't work either ```df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) {x*df[1,"V5"})}, .SDcols = c("V1","V2","V3","V4")] ```, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @ZhongjinLu  You need `x * V5[1]`